# Using React-Native and AWS NoSQL

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, react-native

I'm looking to save users' progress to a database and I'm already using AWS for user authentication. There's an option to add NoSQL support to my AWS project, but there is virtually 0 documentation that clarifies how I can save to the database or retrieve data from it.

Can anybody explain how to use it or point me towards a tutorial that can help explain?

Alternatively, are there any other services/methods I can use to store user data externally?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have many options, but considering you are intend to use the AWS DynamoDB i can give you those:

1) You can create a background api service using any language like java, python, node and running it into a ec2 server and process your requests from there.

2) You can use aws lambda functions in this case you wont need a ec2 server.

3) You can use DynamoDB javacript libraries and connect to your database directly from your APP, but in this case somethings will be a lot harder to do.

Comment: When you say "somethings will be a lot harder to do," can you be a bit more specific? This (#3) is probably the route that I want to go.

Comment: I think controlling the user permissions will be harder to do in this way, because you will need to create roles for the dynamodb access specific to each user, you can just create a global write permission and give it to all users, otherwise with some credential with permission to write someone will be able to change other user data.

Comment: When creating a table in AWS, the first step is establishing permissions for read/write between users, so I'm not sure that will actually be a problem.

Comment: I mean that it will be harder to control specific user access to each document in the same table.

Take a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

Comment: I think you will be able to do it, the link i sent above there is this paragraph.

Limiting User Access

Many IAM permissions policies allow users to access only those items in a table where the partition key value matches the user identifier. For example, the game app preceding limits access in this way so that users can only access game data that is associated with their user ID. The IAM substitution variables ${www.amazon.com:user_id}, ${graph.facebook.com:id}, and ${accounts.google.com:sub} contain user identifiers for login with Amazon, Facebook, and Google.

Comment: Interesting... I'm new to backend dev, so this is good to know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) for your React Native application, which has support for using GraphQL on the client and interfacing with DynamoDB as your NoSQL store. AppSync has support for JavaScript clients including a React Native sample application and SDK.